# How to copy terminal output to a file without using mouse

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, zsh, file-copy

Say I have a bunch of text in the terminal. I can use my mouse/cursor to copy to clipboard but is there a way to copy the last X lines from the terminal to a separate file using a terminal command?

Comment: What terminal ?

Comment: any terminal, with bash or zsh running?